# Editing host file to redirect www.somesite.com to localhost/somesite

Tags: redirect, localhost, host

I develop multiple sites, so i have one folder for each site for eg.
localhost/firstsite for www.firstsite.com
localhost/secondesite for www.secondsite.com

I want the host file to redirect to the specific folder when i type a webaddress for eg.

when i type www.firstsite.com it should go to localhost/firstsite.

Comment: please describe what machine you are using. are you serving these files on an Apache?. Please be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below... it will help you..

**Go to IIS Manager** `inetmgr`

**Add a New Website**

[image]

**Create a Website like below :**

[image]

**Create a Second Site like below :**

[image]

Now `www.firstsite.com` will redirect to `localhost/firstsite` and `www.secondsite.com` will redirect to `localhost/secondesite`